# Login and add to cart functionality stop working after outage

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I've made a site using Magento. At one point my internet service went down (and since has been restored). However, since the outage, my login and add to cart functionality stopped working. I tried to solve this by clearing the cookies from localhost (where the site is hosted) and the server's sessions files.

I also tried clearing the Magento cache.

The strange part is that this happened one more time before, but I don't know how it was solved without my intervention. I'm using Magento 2.2.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved after i tried to enter with firefox. I mention that i was using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Flush the browser cache and cookies, it will fix your issue